# Display variable names when hovering a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, r, echarts

Here's a plot made with `{echarts4r}` that comes from [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/125#issuecomment-581152750):

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("model") %>%  
  e_charts(mpg) %>%
  e_y_axis(drat) %>%
  e_scatter(drat, symbol_size = 15, bind = model, scale = NULL) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
              function(params){
                return('<strong>' + params.name +  
              '</strong><br />x-axis: ' + params.value[0] +  
                '<br />y-axis: ' + params.value[1]
                )} 
              "))
```

As you can see, the name of the car model and the values are displayed when you hover a point. However, I don't know how to display the variable names in the same way. I know I could manually replace "x-axis" and "y-axis" with their names but I would like to do it automatically.

I checked the [documentation of echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter) about this, but using `{a}` (for example) does not work.

Any idea?

Edit: I use `echarts4r 0.3.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you are asking for does not exist in the params passed for e_tooltip.
you can access them by passing `params` to the `console.log` and inspecting this log in the browser:

```
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("model") %>%  
  e_charts(mpg) %>%
  e_y_axis(drat) %>%
  e_scatter(drat, symbol_size = 15, bind = model, scale = NULL) %>%
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
              function(params){
              var obj_str = JSON.stringify(params);
              console.log(obj_str);
                return('<strong>' + params.name +  
              '</strong><br />' + params.seriesName + ': ' + params.value[0] +  
                '<br />mpg: ' + params.value[1]
                )} 
              "))
```

you will note that the x-axis name is under `params.seriesName` but the y-axis name is not found.

here is an example of what you'd find if you were to inspect the `console.log` for `params`:

```
{"componentType":"series",
  "componentSubType":"scatter",
  "componentIndex":0,
  "seriesType":"scatter",
  "seriesIndex":0,
  "seriesId":"\u0000drat\u00000",
  "seriesName":"drat",
  "name":"Ford Pantera L",
  "dataIndex":9,
  "data":{"value":[15.8,4.22],
  "name":"Ford Pantera L"},
  "value":[15.8,4.22],
  "color":"#c23531",
  "dimensionNames":["x","y"],
  "encode":{"x":[0],"y":[1]},
  "marker":"<span style=\"display:inline-block;
            margin-right:5px;
            border-radius:10px;
            width:10px;height:10px;
            background-color:#c23531;\"></span>",
  "$vars":["seriesName","name","value"]
}
```

In this case, the `paste0` approach of @Edo below seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand if I'm onto something you may actually need...
I supposed that the reason why you want flexible names is to have it a separated function so to call you whenever you need...

So how about this? It uses a workaround to avoid names (in the sense that you pass strings to the function instead of unquoted names). However, if you need to use names, we can try something else.

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tibble)


plot_escatter <- function(df, x_axis, y_axis, bind){
    
    df %>%
        e_charts_ (x_axis) %>%
        e_y_axis_ (y_axis) %>%
        e_scatter_(y_axis, symbol_size = 15, bind = bind, scale = NULL) %>%
        e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(paste0("
              function(params){
                return('<strong>' + params.name + '</strong><br />", x_axis, ": ' + params.value[0] +  
                '<br />", y_axis, ": ' + params.value[1]
                )} 
              ")))
    
}


mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column("model") %>%  
    plot_escatter("mpg", "drat", "model")
```

Comment: This is almost right. I use this plot in a shiny app in which the user can choose both axis. That's why I can't just manually write the names of the axis (I don't know what variables the user will choose). I can use `paste0()` with success in my app, though I don't need to create a custom function to do so. It does the job (so I upvote your answer) and I don't know why I didn't think of it before, but I was looking for a "cleaner" solution: using only JS and not `paste0()` would be better.

Comment: I see what you mean. I never seen that package before, so I need to study it up a bit to help you out better.. If I find something, I'll let you know. What does the user provide to the chart? Strings or names? Is the use of strings and `*_` functions fine for you? Is it just the JS part that you want to improve?

Comment: The user provides inputs which are strings. Yes, I'm fine with the use of `_*` functions and strings, I only want to improve the JS part in `e_tooltip`. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: The function `JS` just takes all the inputs, `paste` them together with `collapse = "\n"` and add the new class `JS_EVAL`. Just read the function: `print(htmlwidgets::JS)`. Therefore, I believe the solution with `paste0` is the right way to handle your problem.

Comment: Sure it works, but I was wondering if there is a way that uses only JS. For example, in the code in my post, I use `params.name` or `params.value[1]` to print particular arguments. My question is if there exist such parameters to print the name of the two axis.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the code below:

You need to use **params.seriesName** for accessing column name

```
    mtcars %>%   
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") %>%  
  e_charts(wt) %>%  
  e_scatter(mpg, qsec, bind = model, scale = NULL) %>% 
  e_tooltip(formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(" 
    function(params){ 
      return('<strong>' + params.seriesName + 
              '</strong><br />wt: ' + params.value[0] +  
              '<br />mpg: ' + params.value[1] + '<br> qsec:' + params.value[2]   
              )} 
        "))
```

Comment: This is not what I want because you just wrote the name of the variables instead of `x-axis` and `y-axis`. What I'm looking for is a way to display the name of the variables without having to specify whether it's `wt` or else. I want to know if there exists something such as `params.name[1]` to access to these variable names